# How to make selenium python open links from txt file one at a time in 1 tab

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How to do I make selenium python open links individually then run a code (already made the code just need to know how to open links from a txt file). I want the links to open in 1 tab only and so after the code I made is done running it opens the next link and runs the same code, any way?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to read file line by line. See more on https://www.journaldev.com/709/java-read-file-line-by-line.

Also you will need a for loop for every line which represent your link. Inside that loop you will navigate to "line" (url) and call same method for every linck.

you can open a new tab with

```
public void openTab() {
        // Open tab 2 using CTRL + T keys.
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL +"t");

        // Open URL In 2nd tab.
        driver.get("http://www.qaautomated.com/p/contact.html");

        // Call switchToTab() method to switch to the first tab
        switchToTab();

        // Call switchToTab() method to switch to the second tab.
        switchToTab();
    }
```